# No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document in a taglib file

Tags: java, xml, taglib

Eclipse galileo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" 
        version="2.0">
</taglib>
```

How can I get rid of the warning? Application works fine, looks like an IDE issue or something. I am aware of that I can disable warning checks but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
```

to

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
```

Be sure that `xsd` is available by http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd
In this case it unavailable.

Comment: Results in a different error: "The errors below were detected when validating the file "webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" via the file "taglib.tld".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd is validated in the context of taglib.tld." If I take a look at the error details, numerous entries like: "s4s-elt-character non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation"

Comment: I recheck looks like xsd unavailable by `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd` url. If you have this xsd locally you can change url on local path `xsd/webjsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd` for instance

Comment: CAMOBAP - thanks for pointing this out, non-existing schemaLocation was the root of the problem. Modified the taglib tag.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" 
        version="2.1">
</taglib>

The warning was gone. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: If this solution helped you. Please apply my answer.

Comment: @Łukasz you need vote up (button above zero), and sect check (it becomes green

Comment: Voete up requires 15 reputation :(